# mysql - combine count and display in column

Tags: mysql

My requirement is to create a view. Below are the input:

```
gid     tid         c1  c2  c3  
20304   23233       5   6   2
20304   23423       3   2   6
20304   23567       0   3   2
20304   23784       0   0   0
```

Where c1, c2 and c3 are last 3 days columns name. i.e. if today is 17th Dec, I want to capture the data of 16th Dec, 15th dec and 14th Dec.

I have a transaction table from where I am getting gid, tid. Count can be derived from multiple row group by tid and date. Below is the query.

It is possible that if for 1 gid and tid we may get count for one day but we on other day we might not get gid and tid.

```
SELECT
    gid,
    tid,
    count(*) as count1,
    modifiedDate,
    CURDATE() as today
from mbm
WHERE modifiedDate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND modifiedDate <= CURDATE()
GROUP BY gid, tId, DATE_FORMAT(modifiedDate,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Using this query I am getting below result:

```
gid     tid     count1
25494   25648   1
20202   25733   1
20202   25727   1
25494   25705   2
25403   25693   2
25494   25648   2
25489   25639   2
25403   25630   2
25494   25617   1
25489   25605   1
25403   25593   1
25155   25584   2
25494   25507   1
25489   25501   1
21522   25462   1
21522   25456   1
25403   25410   1
25155   25295   1
25155   25283   1
24909   25261   1
```

How do I get result in above mentioned format? What should I use? Union?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I think union will not work.. Can I write procedure to count data and put it in view?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sum` and `case` to achieve this:

```
select gid,tid,
sum(case when modifiedDate >= curdate() - interval 1 day 
          and modifiedDate < curdate() then count1 else 0 end) as c1,
sum(case when modifiedDate >= curdate() - interval 2 day 
          and modifiedDate < curdate() - interval 1 day then count1 else 0 end) as c2,
sum(case when modifiedDate >= curdate() - interval 3 day 
          and modifiedDate < curdate() - interval 2 day then count1 else 0 end) as c3
from mbm
group by gid,tid;
```

Comment: I tried your option @Tom Mac,  but it gives me "Invalid of group function". I think use of condition in case causes issues..!!!

Comment: Actually I have used count(*) instead of count1 and that is the issue.. can I write a select query because count1 is not available directly. I have to derive it